# Why is Darchei Moshe split into two versions: the short (Hakatzer) and the long (Ha'aruch)?

Tags: jewish-books, tur

The standard Tur is printed with the main commentaries including the Beis Yosef and the Darchei Moshe. In every edition I have seen the Darchei Moshe is presented in the following way: on the same page as the Tur/Beis Yosef and in the back of the book after the Tur/Beis Yosef. The one on the page are selections of what he wrote on the Tur/Beis Yosef and the one in the back is everything he wrote (and from what I've seen they include the ones that are printed on the page with the Tur). 
My question is why aren't all of the Darchei Moshe's comments printed on the same page as the Tur/Beis Yosef? And if this was a publishers decision for formatting purposes (or whatever considerations publishers might have) who chose which comments would appear on the page and why those specific ones?

Comment: It's definitely Aroch (long) not Aruch (set).

Comment: @doubleaa, I concur, but I've heard people pronounce it the other way, so I didn't edit it; it's a (rather irritating, IMHO) colloquialism.

Comment: Much of the additional material in the longer one is just straight quotes from the Bet Yosef.

Comment: Doesn't the Tur on the Torah also have a long and short version?

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree but I spelled it the way I have heard most people say the word. I guess it's similar to how people say "Sha'ar Tzion" in the Mishna Berurah when really it's Sha'ar Tziun.

Comment: @sam , it does.

Comment: @Gavriel Same with the Ohr Hatzafun (often misspelled as Ohr Hatzafon) of the Alter of Slabodka.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the Beth Yosef was published while Rabbi Moshe Isserles was at work on the Darkhei Moshe (Haaroch), when he recognized that Rabbi Yosef Karo's commentary to the Tur largely met his objectives, Rabbi Moshe Isserles published the Darkhei Moshe in a modified form- Darkhei Moshe Hakatsar, Only things that the Beth Yosef didn't already commented on the Tur- This Is the short form of Darkhei Moshe (Hakatsar).

According to the above- Rabbi Moshe Isserles chose which comments would appear. The publishers prefer to put the short form of the Darkhei Moshe on the page so the learning of the Tur would be more continuous learning, but gives you the option to see the long form in the back of the book, if needed.

Actually its very comfortable, and therefore all the modern publishers Arrange it this way.

Comment: This answer does not fit with [this observation](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33482/why-is-darchei-moshe-split-into-two-versions-the-short-hakatzer-and-the-long#comment85274_33482)

Comment: This is highly unlikely as there is Darkei Moshe Haaroch on Aveilut. Why would he finish it after starting his new plan?

Comment: Im not sure You right, from my expirience he quotes LIKE the beth Yosef and not FROM him. Even though he might quote from him as it published while he still working on the Darkhei Moshe. I would love to see Mekorot of exact quote if you have some...